# How to change the whole domain name without refreshing the page using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, redirect, url-rewriting

- I have this domain name : mydomain.ga
- I want to change it to : ourdomain.com

*/ Note : I want only my domain name looks like that : "ourdomain.com" on the nav bar browser after the loading of the page directly without any redirect or update in the page, i've used this code but the broblem is it redirects the page the new domain name , but in my case i want that my code doesn't redirect the page or make any change, only the domain name looking like that after "ourdomain.com" after the page loading directly, This is my code:

```
 <script>
 var url= "http://www.ourdomain.com"; 
 window.location = url;
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use html, the only way to redirect without any redirect or update is to use iframe but it is really not clean:

```
<iframe src = "https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="border:0;width: 100%;height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

To do it cleaner you should use htaccess redirect:

https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess/

Comment: No this is not what i want, i want only after the page display its content the url browser just change from mydomain.ga to ourdomain.col